# Querying Encrypted Model Data in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

A requirement of an application I am making is that all user data (emails, addresses, date of birth, etc...) be encrypted. So, I use a trait like the one found [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/encrypting-model-data). This, however, brings up an issue when querying the data like below.

```
$user = User::where("email", "=", $email);
```

Since I am searching encrypted data, the above query will not work as intended.

A rather naive solution I thought of is to decrypt the entire dataset before querying like so

```
$data = User::all();
$cnt = count($data);
for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++){/* decrypt record i */}
```

But this is very impractical and expensive. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

thats means in your db, you **store encrypted email right**?

just query like this..

```
$user = User::where("email", your_encryption_function($email));
echo your_decryption_method($user->email); //result
```

EDIT

You are recommended to use Ciphersweet library if you intended to encrypt your database data.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-ciphersweet

Comment: This cant work. `$email` is a plain string, and you decrypt it? That would give invalid payload exception.

Comment: This can work. In DB there is encrypted data and you put decrypt value in where condition.

Comment: this wouldn't work, if you encrypt a string again, the result would be different from the value you got from the first time you encrypted it. because if you would get the same value from encrypting the same string twice, then it would be a huge insecurity issue.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. If the value in the column is encrypted and you decrypt a variable which I assume is plain text - but lets assume it's encrypted as well.. your evaluating an encrypted value from the database against a decrypted value which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

I just found a package that does exactly like this.

The package name is [Ciphersweet](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-ciphersweet) made by [Spatie](https://github.com/spatie) himself.

===================

I have thought of this before and I came up with two setup:

**First scenario:**

Encrypt the `$request->email` first then compare it to the email values on the database.

This will not work because the two encrypted values can have different output values.

**Second scenario:**

Decrypt email values from the database first before comparing it to the `$request->email` value.

Will work, but imagine having tens of thousands of saved rows on your db???

Very impractical and absurd to do.

**Conclusion:**

It will be hard to make a search on encrypted values on the database. Imagine also the routine of decrypting the values every time you need to display them on the pages?

Well, I hope someone can suggest how this can work. I'll be happy to be wrong here because I want to encrypt data on my db if given a practical solution.